# Shimano 105 v Tiagra

Tags: gears

I have a new Giant Fastroad, with 10 speed Tiagra, my old bike (7-8 years old) has 9 speed 105.
I think that the 105 was smoother even on the old bike, would the 105 be compatible to fit to the new bike and be able to cope with the extra gear?

Comment: OraNob replied considering the desire to just change the shifters... I replied considering changing the entire grouppo...  Together our replies give you some options.

Comment: How many miles have you put on the Tiagra groupset? The latest 105/Tiagra can feel a little stiff and clunky at first but get noticeably smoother after a few hundred miles. Changing to such an old groupset seems like a backward step.

Comment: Have done 5 or 6 hundred miles now and am getting used to it, it does feel better than it did at first. I will stick with it and hope it stays good.

Answer (score 2):

Shimano 9 speed has a different pull ratio to 10 speed.
So this wouldn't be possible.
If your Tiagra is the newer 4700 series - the cabling is routed under the tape - which gives a cleaner line but I found on my Shimano 5700 105 (vs the older 5600 external routing) gave a stiffer shift.

I have found on servicing my cables with lubed and sealed Jagwire - the shifting has improved greatly though.

Answer (score 0):

The change over to your 105 drivetrain should be pretty straight forward.  Here are some things that you should consider...

1. The rear hub:  Fortunately for you this should not be an issue provided you change the cassette to be a 9 speed cassette.  Fortunately the cassette body on the hub is the same for 9 and 10 speed so no issue here
2. Shifters and deraileurs:  Since I assume from your text you have both systems you will just need to remove and replace the parts...  Nothing here but moving things around
3. Chains:  you will need to ensure you have a 9 speed chain on the 9 speed bike and a 10 speed chain on the 10 speed bike.
4. Cranksets:  Purists may say you need to change them was well... my experience is it really does not matter but the perfectionist in me would keep the grouppos together so I would keep 105 cranks with the 105 grouppo and the Tiagra with Tiagra.
5. Cables and Housing:  There is a chance the cable routing differs or is of different lenghth... so if it was me I would just plan on replacing the housing and cables.
6. Cassettes:  The Tiagra is new and probably fine... if your 105 cassette is old get a new one and pair it with a new 9 speed chain and everything will feel brand new.

Finally, you may need to get some new bar tape depending on how careful you are removing the tape to get the Brifters off.  In the end I think you can salvage everything pretty easily to put the Tiagra on your old bike and the 105 on your new.

Good Luck

Comment: I think OP was asking to change the old 105 shifters only - since the OP is asking whether it can cope with the "extra gear". Maybe OP needs to clarify more - but that is my interpretation.

Comment: @OraNob after a re-read you are probably correct... taking both our replies together will give OP some options. cheers.

Comment: I changed from 9 speed Tiagra to a 105 groupset. It was fairly straightforward and is certainly possible. I did it for the same reason too! In hindsight though it was quite a time consuming job and if I were to do it again I'd probably just get my local bike shop to do it. Depending on skill you might need half a day or more..